# split column data frame into multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame with one column that looks like this

```
df = read.table(file="sprint.m.df.txt", sep="\t", quote="", header=TRUE)

    X.Rank...Time...Wind...Name...Country...Birthdate...City...Date.
1     1 9.58 0.9 "Usain Bolt" "JAM" "21.08.86" "Berlin" "16.08.2009"
2     2 9.63 1.5 "Usain Bolt" "JAM" "21.08.86" "London" "05.08.2012"
3      3 9.69 0 "Usain Bolt" "JAM" "21.08.86" "Beijing" "16.08.2008"
4      3 9.69 2 "Tyson Gay" "USA" "09.08.82" "Shanghai" "20.09.2009"
5 3 9.69 -0.1 "Yohan Blake" "JAM" "26.12.89" "Lausanne" "23.08.2012"
6      6 9.71 0.9 "Tyson Gay" "USA" "09.08.82" "Berlin" "16.08.2009"
```

i have been trying to split the column into multiple columns using string splits and other methods but nothing is working.

How can i split the data frame so i can end up with a data frame as

```
 X.rank | Time | wind | name       | country | birthdate| city    | date
    1      9.58  0.9    Usian Bolt    jam       21.08.86  Berlin    16.08.2009
```

Comment: You get that when reading the data? Using csv, xlsx?

Comment: @AlbertoTorrejonValenzuela i added how the data is read. Im supposed to split it into a data frame. I know that by using `sep = " "` fixes the problem but im supposed to use string manipulation.

Comment: Apply `str_split_fixed(string, pattern)` by columns using `" "` as pattern

Comment: Did you try `df = read.table(file="sprint.m.df.txt", sep=" ")`

Comment: @ChrisS. yes i did but im supposed to read it as it was given and get the data frame from it.

Comment: That makes no sense, but you can read it again with the readr package `read_delim(df[,1], delim=" ", col_names=c("rank", "Time", "wind", "name", "country", "birthdate", "city", "date"))`

Comment: Can you edit your post to include first few lines of `sprint.m.df.txt` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spaces within quotes makes the column difficult to parse but it's easy to read.  See my comments above and use `read.table(file="sprint.m.df.txt", sep=" ")`  or if you really *have* to work with your `df`, then try `read_delim` or `scan`.

```
df8 <- readr::read_delim(df[,1], delim=" ", col_names =FALSE)
# OR
df8 <- data.frame(matrix(scan(text=df[,1], what=" "), ncol=8, byrow=TRUE))
colnames(df8) <- c("rank", "Time", "wind", "name", "country", "birthdate", "city", "date")
df8
  rank Time wind        name country birthdate     city       date
1    1 9.58  0.9  Usain Bolt     JAM  21.08.86   Berlin 16.08.2009
2    2 9.63  1.5  Usain Bolt     JAM  21.08.86   London 05.08.2012
3    3 9.69    0  Usain Bolt     JAM  21.08.86  Beijing 16.08.2008
4    3 9.69    2   Tyson Gay     USA  09.08.82 Shanghai 20.09.2009
5    3 9.69 -0.1 Yohan Blake     JAM  26.12.89 Lausanne 23.08.2012
6    6 9.71  0.9   Tyson Gay     USA  09.08.82   Berlin 16.08.2009
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a tribble with the tibble package

```
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(
~X, ~RankTime, ~Wind, ~Name, ~Country, ~Birthdate, ~City, ~Date, 
1, 9.58, 0.9, "Usain Bolt", "JAM", "21.08.86", "Berlin", "16.08.2009",
2, 9.63, 1.5, "Usain Bolt", "JAM", "21.08.86", "London", "05.08.2012",
3, 9.69, 0, "Usain Bolt", "JAM", "21.08.86", "Beijing", "16.08.2008",
3, 9.69, 2, "Tyson Gay", "USA", "09.08.82", "Shanghai", "20.09.2009",
3, 9.69, -0.1, "Yohan Blake", "JAM", "26.12.89", "Lausanne", "23.08.2012",
6, 9.71, 0.9, "Tyson Gay", "USA", "09.08.82", "Berlin", "16.08.2009")

df

# output
# A tibble: 6 x 8
      X RankTime  Wind Name        Country Birthdate City     Date      
  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <chr>   <chr>     <chr>    <chr>     
1     1     9.58   0.9 Usain Bolt  JAM     21.08.86  Berlin   16.08.2009
2     2     9.63   1.5 Usain Bolt  JAM     21.08.86  London   05.08.2012
3     3     9.69   0   Usain Bolt  JAM     21.08.86  Beijing  16.08.2008
4     3     9.69   2   Tyson Gay   USA     09.08.82  Shanghai 20.09.2009
5     3     9.69  -0.1 Yohan Blake JAM     26.12.89  Lausanne 23.08.2012
6     6     9.71   0.9 Tyson Gay   USA     09.08.82  Berlin   16.08.2009
```

Comment: how dows this answer OPs question? Do you suggest du copy the data manually?

Comment: As user763708 is new to stackoverflow my intention was to provide a immediate help to get a dataframe to work with. The question is the following : "How can i split the data frame so i can end up with a data frame as ...". I am aware that my approach is basically not one with code! But in the beginning of my programming time I had the same problems. So I decided to provide this help for a newbie to answer his question "How can i split the data frame so i can end up with a data frame as ...". This is a basis where user763708 can start and evolve further. There was nothing bad in my mind. :-).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Good point of yours :)